# Adding ints from array

Tags: arrays, mips

Im taking CompArch for the first time ever. I have to print out an array

```
list:   .word 3, 0, 1, 2, 6, -2, 4, 7, 3, 7
```

I managed to print it out in two rows

```
R1  3 0 1 2 6    
R2 -2 4 7 3 7
```

How can i create a loop or code to add all the numbers in the first row. Or in other words the first 5 ints from the array. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why doesn't it work? If you already managed to print the numbers, summing them can't be too far away

Comment: @Leeor I loaded the first five ints of list into a $r where it would print out only the first 5

Comment: Sounds like all you have to do is extract them one by one through shifting and masking

Comment: @leeor how would i do that?